# update column values of few records

Tags: mysql, vb.net, field, records

Using mysql, vb.net 2008
I want to update column values of few records with sequence of numbers, as below.

```
             col1      col2
rec1          10        12
rec2          5         13
rec3          15        9
rec4          20        11
rec5          3         7
```

I want to update col1 values of rec1, rec2, rec3 with values 1, 2, 3
So, if I have n number of records to update, I wish the values in col1 as  1, 2, 3, ... n

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an `AutoIncrementColumn` in order to make sure your records are concurrent that you want... When you do this your columns would go from 1,2,3,4 and so on.

```
 CREATE TABLE animals 
 (
  id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: Thank you but my table has no autoincrement column and no primary key.